# gcloud cli authentication with google workspace scopes not allowed - "this app is blocked"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-workspace

I am attempting to deploy some GCP and Google Workspace resources via Terraform. I am using a GCP identity which has admin access to both GCP and Workspace. Everything is fine when I perform the actions manually in `console.cloud.google.com` and `admin.google.com`.

I can deploy the GCP resources via Terraform without issue after performing a `gcloud auth application-default login` then referencing the GCP provider

```
provider "google" {
  project = var.project
  region  = "us-central1"
  zone    = "us-central1-c"
}
```

When I attempt to add in Google Workspace resources...

```
provider "googleworkspace" {
  customer_id = var.workspace_customer_id
}

resource "googleworkspace_role" "IntegrationRole" {
  name = var.common_resource_name
  privileges {
    privilege_name = "ORGS_RETRIEVE_PRIVILEGE_GROUP"
    service_id     = "..."
  }
}
```

I get the following error.

```
 Error: googleapi: Error 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "method": "ccc.hosted.frontend.directory.v1.DirectoryRoles.Insert",
│       "service": "admin.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT"
│   }
│ ]
│
│ More details:
│ Reason: insufficientPermissions, Message: Insufficient Permission
```

In researching this, it seems I need to provide the appropriate scopes to perform actions in Google Workspace. So I do so...

```
gcloud auth application-default login \
    --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.rolemanagement,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user
```

But when attempting to approve this I get the following error.

[image]

[image]

I have attempted to turn on "less secure app settings" but the result is the same.

How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you passed the verification process from Google? This seems related to the [100 OAuth users cap](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en#unverified-app-user-cap:~:text=app%20to%20complete.-,Unverified%20app%20user%20cap,-To%20protect%20users) when you use an unverified public app.

Comment: This isn't a custom app I am building. It is straight gcloud cli. It is using the "Google Auth Library" app which seems to just be baked into the cli.